# change name of attribute for has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

is it possible to change name of the attribute for a has_and_belongs_to_many association? something like

```
  class User
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, as: :friends
```

so that User.friends returns other users rather than User.users?

Comment: How does your join table look like? `user_id, friend_id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: 'User'
```

You might need to specify the join table, depending on your setup

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: 'User', join_table: '...'
```

Can read more about all of this here [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)